# Why do ice hockey players get thrown out of the face off circle?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

Why are players thrown out of a face-off? I've heard there is a certain procedure for these circumstances, but I haven't found a list of things that are considered 'illegal'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the Official NHL (National Hockey League) Rulebook in rule 76.6, players must comply by the following standards, otherwise it will result in a face-off violation:

> i) Encroachment by any player other than the center into the face-off
>   area prior to the puck being dropped.
>
> ii) Encroachment by any player into the area between the hash marks on
>   the outer edges of the face-off circle prior to the puck being
>   dropped. Players must also ensure that both of their skates do not
>   cross their respective hash marks.
>
> iii) Any physical contact with an opponent prior to the puck being
>   dropped.
>
> iv) Failure by either center taking the face-off to properly position
>   himself behind the restraining lines or place his stick on the ice (as
>   outlined in Rule 76.4).
>
> v) The blade of the stick must then be placed on the ice (at least the
>   toe of the blade of the stick) within the designated face-off area.
>
> Violation of these rules will result in removal from the face-off (the
>   center) and normally one of the wingers comes in to take the re-drop.
>
> Any 2 face-off violations committed by the same team during the same
>   face-off will result in a Delay of Game minor penalty for 2 minutes.

Included is also a link to the Official Rulebook for further reading and long form rules:
http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/pdfs/2012-13_RuleBook.pdf